# Scrollbar when zooming in html page

Tags: css, html

kinda a noob question on css

I have a couple of divs

[image]

in a page. Now when I zoom in that page Div 3 (that is currently floating left)
doesn't fit any more so it falls right under Div 2. How can I change this behaviour for the whole page so that a scrollbar appears when I zoom in? I tried setting the overflow-x : scroll for the whole body in  a css but it didn't seem to have any effect.

I made a JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq3Hv/

html

```
<div class="first">div1</div>
<div class="second">div2</div>
<div class="third">div3</div>
<div class="fourth">div4</div>
```

css

```
.first {
    background-color:red;
    width: 400px;
}
.second {
    background-color:blue;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}
.third {
    background-color:green;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}
.fourth {
    clear:both;
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Try to zoom in the browser and you'll see that div3 falls under div2. (In chrome anyway).
I generally want to use a solution that works both in IE8 + and chrome.

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "zooming", by the way?

Comment: You could try changing the divs into inline-blocks instead of floating them.

Comment: I updated the question with more details. Zooming in I mean using the browser zoom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is Add a wrapper div and give total width to it.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/Lq3Hv/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="first">div1</div>
<div class="second">div2</div>
<div class="third">div3</div>
<div class="fourth">div4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: This works indeed. So you reckon that should be used on every page on my web application to make sure they all work properly when zooming in ?

Comment: @sakiskaliakoudas Yes.